# Use proxy middleware with gulp connect

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to use `gulp-connect` to forward all requests to `api/` to `localhost:3000`. I found an example at https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/27

and setup my connect task like this:

```
gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: './app', 
    middleware: function(connect, o) {
      return [ (function() {
        var url = require('url');
        var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
        var options = url.parse('http://localhost:3000/api');
        options.route = 'api';
        return proxy(options);
      })()]
    }
    });
});
```

Running this task warns that `connect deprecated connect(middleware): use app.use(middleware) instead node_modules/gulp-connect/index.js:39:19` and this task does not forward requests as expected.

I looked at the `connect` source to see if I could work around the depreciation, but it is beyond my level in js:

```
 ConnectApp.prototype.server = function() {
    var app, middleware;
    middleware = this.middleware();
    app = connect.apply(null, middleware);
    server = http.createServer(app);
    app.use(connect.directory(typeof opt.root === "object" ? opt.root[0] : opt.root));
    server.listen(opt.port);
    this.log("Server started http://" + opt.host + ":" + opt.port);
    if (opt.livereload) {
      tiny_lr.Server.prototype.error = function() {};
      lr = tiny_lr();
      lr.listen(opt.livereload.port);
      return this.log("LiveReload started on port " + opt.livereload.port);
    }
  };
```

I cannot figure out how to change my gulp-file to use `app.use(middleware)`, the `app` variable is not exported by the connect module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reported issue that should be fixed in the next gulp-connect release on NPM :

https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/commit/9bd7da765d6763bbee566cc5fc03b873ccf93e37
https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/67

Comment: Is it possible to use the build from github in the mean time or is that not recommended?

Comment: In your package.json dependencies map, you can point to a github repo directly.

Answer (score 25):

A solution given by [chimurai](https://github.com/chimurai) on [Github](https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/27#issuecomment-136460485) is to use the [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) package to do that.

For example :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: ['./app'],
        middleware: function(connect, opt) {
            return [
                proxy('/api', {
                    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                    changeOrigin:true
                })
            ]
        }

    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect']);
```

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get middleware to work correctly even when using the github source. I did get the same result with `modrewrite`

```
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: './app',
    port: 8000,
    middleware: function() {
      return [
        modRewrite([
          '^/api/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/api/v1/$1 [P]'
        ])
      ];
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my config to start an express server with livereload (using nodemon) and proxy all API requests to the server.

```
gulp.task('connect', function () {
    var connect = require('connect');

    // Start the Node server to provide the API
    var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
    nodemon({ cwd: '../server', script: 'app.js', ignore: ['node_modules/*'], ext: 'js' })
        .on('restart', function () {
            console.log('Node server restarted!')
        });


    var app = connect()
        // proxy API requests to the node server
        .use(require('connect-modrewrite')(['^/api/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/api/$1 [P]']))
        .use(require('connect-livereload')({ port: 35729 }))
        .use(connect.static('../client'))
        .use(connect.static('../client/.tmp'))
        .use(connect.directory('../client'));

    require('http').createServer(app)
        .listen(9000)
        .on('listening', function () {
            console.log('Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000');
        });
});
```